# MultiChoice doesn't show up in REST service Content Types

Tags: content-type, rest, choice-field, listdata.svc

I've added a multichoice column to a content type, and when I call listdata.svc and look inside of the content types and find the one I want, the multichoice column isn't there. When I change the column to a dropdown it appears in the content types that appear.

Is there any reason why I can't get a multichoice column to show up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default SharePoint REST service does not return multi-value lookup fields, but you could use the `$expand` operator to make a projection in order to return those values.

The following REST query demonstrates how to return multi-value lookup fields:

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Tasks(<ItemId>)?$select=TaskName,TaskCategories&$expand=TaskCategories
```

where `TaskCategories` is the name of multi-choice column.

Answer (score 0):

Because multi-value lookup fields are returned as a string of multiple values, there is no way to query for them (for example, the equivalent of an Includes element or NotIncludes element is not supported).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142385.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9155aabb-ac8c-4e9c-a694-0cb2522609da/rest-services-and-multiple-value-lookup-fields?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious